# Will updating from KitKat to Lollipop delete my data?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop

I have a LENOVO A6000 running KitKat and I want to update it to Lollipop. I have important pictures and videos on my mobile.

Will my data be deleted or remain the same if I update my mobile?

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating through your phone via an official update, the data will not be deleted...

However, if you're trying to update it manually it *MAY* be erased and you will need to take a backup

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on your method of updating or upgrading.**

If you're doing it directly from your phone, officially, from within the settings, then your data is fine.

If you're flashing a ROM or using such method, then unless you backup, your data **will** be deleted.